# How to create line graph use chartjs?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I need create line graph, for example img. 
[image]

1) I don't understand, how delete backround grey.
2) Add dynamic point 0.38 and 2225 and add line.
Help please.

This my code

```
 var canvas = document.getElementById("lineChart");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var data = {
        labels: [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1],
        datasets: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Basic',
                data: [19304,13433,9341,6931,5169, 3885,2927,2159,1853,1502, 1176,911,724,590,491, 400,335,280,239,200]
            }
        ]
    };


    var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx , {
        type: "line",
        data: data
    });
```

Comment: Title does not describe the problem in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Here is an example for how to only show the line and not the fill below.  Basically, you just use the `fill: false` option.

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels:
[0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
      borderWidth: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [19304,13433,9341,6931,5169, 3885,2927,2159,1853,1502, 1176,911,724,590,491, 400,335,280,239,200]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Chart.js Drsw Line on Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true
    },
  }
});
```

2) There is nothing natively built into chart.js to draw lines on the chart, however the same team has created a nice plugin called [chartjs-plugin-annotation](https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-annotation) that you can use to do this.  Here is an example of how to configure a line at the point that you wanted (this would go inside your `options` config.

```
annotation: {
  annotations: [{
    type: 'line',
    mode: 'horizontal',
    scaleID: 'y-axis-0',
    value: 2225,
    borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    borderWidth: 4,
    label: {
      enabled: true,
      content: 'Point Label',
      yAdjust: -16,
    }
  }]
}
```

Here is a [codepen example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/PpeYme) that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try adding datasets:

```
    fill: false,
```

to your dataset

2)Not sure this is possible

This would be a comment but i can't comment yet.